# Get Unicode Numbers Text from Windows Forms Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, numbers

I can Type both English Numbers and Persian Numbers in .net 4 Windows Form Text-box
such as 123 and ۱۲۳ 
but  always i get English numbers from Text-box.Text property 123

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its up to your windows language setting configuration 
in windows 10 x64 with setting (language for non-unicode programs > Persian) i get unicode Number for persian numbers
for example 1777 for ۱

var txt = textBox1.Text;